# Load only first frame of a gif in browser. Is something out there that does this?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, gif

Is there an extension for firefox / plugin for chrome / userscript that can make the browser only load first frame of a `.gif` image rather than (down)loading it entirely.

(gifs take up unnecessarily more of my very limited bandwidth (don't ask) but I don't want to block other friendly images or I'd block all images entirely (like opera does))

Comment: That's an interesting question. From a quick look at the gif89a spec it looks like this would require on-the-fly parsing of the image as the packets came in and then a termination of the connection when the full first frame had been received.

Comment: [image.animation_mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Tips_:_Animated_Images) will stop the animation, but won't prevent the entire file from being downloaded.

Comment: You can also create a block rule for ".gif" in Adblock Plus to block all GIFs, but that may be excessive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) for that.  The bonus is that this is system-level tool, so you can use it in combination with any browser.

From [the manual](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#DEANIMATE-GIFS):

> 8.5.12. deanimate-gifs
>   Typical use:
>
> ```
> Stop those annoying, distracting animated GIF images.
> ```
>
> Effect:
>
> ```
> De-animate GIF animations, i.e. reduce them to their first or last image.
> ```
>
> Type:
>
> ```
> Parameterized.
> ```
>
> Parameter:
>
> ```
> "last" or "first"
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> This will also shrink the images considerably (in bytes, not pixels!). 
>   If the option "first" is given, the first frame of the animation is used as 
>   the replacement. If "last" is given, the last frame of the animation is used 
>   instead, which probably makes more sense for most banner animations, but 
>   also has the risk of not showing the entire last frame (if it is only a 
>   delta to an earlier frame).
>
> You can safely use this action with patterns that will also match 
>   non-GIF objects, because no attempt will be made at anything that doesn't 
>   look like a GIF.

Comment: Nice! If this works and does what Etan said above, seems like it's a perfect solution.

Comment: It seems to, if its claim that it "will also shrink the images considerably" is true.

Comment: Also, I recommend using Privoxy anyway for the rest of its privacy-protecting features!